# Usage of ResponseEntity<T>

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have following code (it's a method in a controller) to download a attachment/Document:

```java
@RequestMapping(value="downloadattachment.htm",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Blob> downloadAttachment(@RequestParam("attachmentid")
        int attachmentId){
    //Attachment is a POJO.
    Attachment attachment= commonDao.getAttachment(attachmentId);

    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

    responseHeaders.setContentType(new MediaType(attachment.getContentType()));
    responseHeaders.set("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; filename=\"" + attachment.getFileName() +"\"");

    return new ResponseEntity<Blob>(attachment.getFileData(), responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

When I run this it gives following error:

> `The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().`

I'm using tiles so my view resolver is:

```xml
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
</bean>
```

Is it related to tiles in some way as all view resolving is happening through tiles definition?

But I think (as according to spring reference), when using `@ResponseBody` or `ResponseEntity<T>`, return type of a handler method is written straight to the HTTP response body(and not placed in a Model, or interpreted as a view name).

Comment: The error concerns the request sent by the client, not the response sent by Spring. The error likely has nothing to do with `ResponseEntity`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the request and not the response.

```
@RequestParam("attachmentid") int attachmentId
```

I think you are not sending parameter attachmentId from client or the request is going to some other controller method.